# How to open GUI app with different $HOME path in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, user-interface, su, home-directory

I'm wondering how I might go about opening a Mac OS X application using a different $HOME path.

Specifically, I'm trying to start a browser and have different sessions, so they don't interfere with each other.

I tried `HOME=/Users/daniel/test open /Applications/Firefox.app/` via BASH, but it didn't work (opened using the existing session from ~/Library). `man open` didn't offer any help.

I then tried creating a different user and did `sudo su mickey -c 'open /Applications/Firefox.app/' and`sudo su mickey -lc 'open /Applications/Firefox.app/', hoping I could at least launch an app as a different user (works in Linux), but again no donut, and `man su` doesn't help here either. It still just opened using my ~/Library stuff.

I know there's some funkiness with environment variables and BASH vs. WM, and I'm guessing I need to do some plist-y magic, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Any ideas?

TIA,
Daniel :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it using `launchctl`. See the [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html). You will need to create a plist for the one-time job. There is a UserName key (see the [launchd.plist man](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html)).